# Removing empty or null values from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
var items = [
    {
        item1: '',
        item2: 'foo'
    },
    {
        item1: 'bar'
        item2: ''
    }
];
```

I'd like to remove all key/value pairs where the value is either empty or null. The following doesn't appear to be working as intended:

```
$.each(items, function(i,v){
    $.each(items[i], function(i2, v2){
        if (v2 === "" || v2 === null){
            delete items[i2];
        }
    });
});
console.log(items);
```

Console log returns the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

How do I get this work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a solution using jQuery `.each`:

```js
var items = [{
  item1: '',
  item2: 'foo'
}, {
  item1: 'bar',
  item2: ''
}];

$.each(items, function(i, v) {
  $.each(v, function(i2, v2) {
    if (v2 === "" || v2 === null) {
      delete v[i2];
    }
  });
});
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your `delete` part was all wrong here:

```
delete items[i2];
```

You are trying to delete a property (for example `item1`) from `items` not from the item itself.

Answer (score 2):

With plain Javascript, you could iterate the array and the all keys and check for empty string or `null` value, then delete if.

```js
var items = [{ item1: '', item2: 'foo' }, { item1: 'bar', item2: '' }];

items.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (o[k] === '' || o[k] === null) {
            delete o[k];
        }
    });
});

console.log(items);
```

Comment: I think I tried to overcomplicate this unnecessarily, your solution is much better.